# "Errors" upgrading from VS2010 to VS2012

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

We have an WPF application developed on Visual Studio 2010 and I've been tasked with upgrading it to VS 2012. It compiles fine in VS2010 and doesn't prompt to upgrade after opening the solution file with VS2012 (Update 3). It also compiles fine in VS2012. However, I get errors in the in-editor Error List even though it compiles and runs without complaint.

These errors are all of the type "Could not find file 'C:\project\src\ui\images\foo.png'" The files don't exist in 'C:\project\src\ui\images\' but rather in 'C:\project\assets\images\' - in the csproj file, we add the images with the following lines (same in both 2010 and 2012):

```
<Resource Include="..\assets\images\foo.png">
   <Link>ui\images\foo.png</Link>
</Resource>
```

My first guess is that 2012 is defaulting to a different URI path than 2010, but I haven't found any documentation about any such change.

The phantom errors show up whether 2012 is targeting the 4.0 or the 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded your VS 2010 to have VS 2010 SP1 installed and rebuild your project before upgrading to VS 2012?
Some incompatibilities problems may occur in upgrading VS 2010 project to VS 2012 project if you haven't upgraded your VS 2010 to VS 2010 SP1.

Comment: I've just checked - yes, this is an upgrade from VS 2010 SP1.